# Showing up a widget inside a widget with animation when button pressed in Qt

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

I've got a window like that:
[image: window1]

If I press the blue button, another widget should be shown with animation and the final view should look like that:
[image: after pressed]

As you realized, the buttons in a layout. I'm trying to make that by changing the minimum size of the blue widget, hiding 2 date pickers and labels. But it's too hard and ugly way. So I need another cute way. Please, share your idea(or code), thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed with 3 widgets, one QTabWidget and one QToolButton. I put QTabWidget into a widget, then wrote styles for both of them. Then I added a widget, changed it's background color to dark blue, then it's size same as toolButton's. I used QPropertyAnimation for animating the dark-blue widget. When the toolButton pressed, the dark-blue widget are brought to front, then animation starts. I put all of them into another widget, gave no layout to it.